# Formatar número com Javascript

Tags: javascript, formatação, number-format

Preciso formatar números inteiros, exemplo:

```
let num = 1234567;
// saída 1.234.567
```

Porém, se o número que vier possuir casas decimais que apareça no máximo duas casas decimais. Exemplo:

```
let num = 1234567.891
// saída 1.234.567,89

let num2 = 123.4
// saída 123,4
```

Ou seja, se for um número inteiro mostra formatado sem casas decimais, agora se vier um número com casas decimais, mostrar 2 casas no máximo.

Meu código funciona até certo ponto, quando o tamanho passa de 6 não formata mais. Está fazendo assim:

```
let num = 1234567;
// saída 1234.567
```

Abaixo meu código:

```
export function fmtoNumero(val, n = 2, x = 3, s = '.', c = ',') {       
    let numval = Number(val);
    let re = '\\d(?=(\\d{' + x + '})(\\D|$))';

    numval = numval.toString().replace('.', c);
    numval = numval.replace(new RegExp(re, 'g'), '$&' + (s || ','));
    return numval;
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ao invés de usar expressões regulares, você pode usar API's nativas do JavaScript para alcançar o mesmo resultado de forma mais simples.

Para fixar o número de casas decimais, você pode usar o método `toFixed`:

```
(999.9).toFixed(2) // "999.90"
(100.158).toFixed(2) // "100.16"
```

Para formatar o número separando os milhares por vírgula, você pode usar o método `toLocaleString`:

```
(987654321).toLocaleString('pt-BR') // "987.654.321"
(9876543.21).toLocaleString('pt-BR') // "9.876.543,21"
```

No entanto, se você quiser combinar os dois, o mais lógico seria encadear os dois, mas esse não é o caso, visto que ambos os métodos retornam uma **string**. Então, vamos utilizar somente o método `toLocaleString`, passando algumas opções como segundo argumento:

```
(987654.321).toLocaleString('pt-BR', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 2,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
}) // "987.654,32"
```

#### Referência e leitura recomendada:

- [How to use toLocaleString() and toFixed(2) in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31581011/how-to-use-tolocalestring-and-tofixed2-in-javascript);
- [`Number.prototype.toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed);
- [`Number.prototype.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString).

Answer (score 5):

Complementando a [resposta aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368512/112052), existe ainda outra alternativa, que é usar um [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat). Seu funcionamento é similar a [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString):

```js
let formatador = new Intl.NumberFormat('pt-BR',
    { minimumFractionDigits: 0, maximumFractionDigits: 2 }
);

[ 987654.321, 987654321 ].forEach(n => {
    console.log(`formatar ${n} = ${formatador.format(n)}`);
});
```

[Segundo a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#Performance), usar um `NumberFormat` é mais vantajoso se você precisar formatar uma grande quantidade de números. E fazendo um [teste básico](https://jsbench.me/cmk6rz55pw/1), de fato a solução com `NumberFormat` se mostrou bem mais rápida.