# Como eu posso fazer para sempre que colocar decimais na minha calculadora eles tenham um ponto ? a linguagem é JavaScript!

Tags: javascript

Seguinte amigos, estou criando uma calculadora para o projeto da facul e ja fiz 95% só falta conseguir deixar ela automatica sempre que eu digitar numeros como por exemplo: 1000 teria que sair **1.000** e 10000 teria que sair **10.000** etc... Poderiam me ajudar pf?

Código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Calculadora</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/calculadora.css">
<!-- Adicione aqui seus scripts para testar -->
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calculadora">
    <input type="text" id="resultado" disabled /><br>

    <button onclick="pegarNum(this)">1</button>
    <button onclick="pegarNum(this)">2</button>
    <button onclick="pegarNum(this)">3</button>
    <button onclick="operador(this)">+</button><br>

    <button onclick="pegarNum(this)">4</button>
    <button onclick="pegarNum(this)">5</button>
    <button onclick="pegarNum(this)">6</button>
    <button onclick="operador(this)">-</button><br>

    <button onclick="pegarNum(this)">7</button>
    <button onclick="pegarNum(this)">8</button>
    <button onclick="pegarNum(this)">9</button>
    <button onclick="operador(this)">*</button><br>

    <button onclick="pegarNum(this)">.</button>
    <button onclick="pegarNum(this)">0</button>
    <button onclick="limparTudo()">C</button>
    <button onclick="operador(this)">/</button><br>
    <button onclick="igual()">=</button> 

    </div>


    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

O código JavaScript é esse:

```
let numero = "";
let telaCalculadora = "";
let termo = [undefined,undefined,undefined];
let resultado = "";



function pegarNum(num){   
    numero = numero.concat(num.innerHTML);                         
    mostrarNaTela(num.innerHTML);    
}


function limparMemoria(){
    numero = "";
    termo = [undefined,undefined,undefined];
    resultado = "";
}

function mostrarNaTela(conteudo){
    telaCalculadora = telaCalculadora.concat(conteudo);
    let tela = document.getElementById('resultado');
    tela.value = telaCalculadora;
}

function limparTela(){
    telaCalculadora = "";
    let tela = document.getElementById('resultado');
    tela.value = telaCalculadora;
}

function limparTudo(){
    limparMemoria();
    limparTela();
}



function operador(op){

    if (numero != ""){
        if(termo[1] == undefined){
            termo[0] = numero;
            termo[1] = op.innerHTML;
            mostrarNaTela(op.innerHTML);
            numero = ""; 
        }
      }
    }

function igual(){
    if(termo[0] != undefined && termo[1] != undefined && numero != ""){

        termo[2] = numero;

        switch(termo[1]){
            case '+':
                resultado = Number(termo[0]) + Number(termo[2]);
            break;

            case '-':
                resultado = Number(termo[0]) - Number(termo[2]);
            break;

            case '*':
                resultado = Number(termo[0]) * Number(termo[2]);
            break;

            case '/':
                resultado = Number(termo[0]) / Number(termo[2]);
            break;
        }

        let salvarResultado = resultado;
        limparTela();
        mostrarNaTela(resultado)
        limparMemoria();
        numero = salvarResultado.toString();

    }else if(termo[0] != undefined && termo[1] != undefined && numero == ""){
        let erro = "Erro de operação";
        limparTela();
        mostrarNaTela(erro);        
        limparMemoria();        
    }


}
```

Comment: *"colocar decimais na minha calculadora"* não seriam milhares? não precisa do *"a linguagem é JavaScript!"* no título, já tem na tag ;)

Comment: Na duplicada sugerida acima, a [resposta aceita](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/368512/112052) sugere usar `toLocaleString`, que além de ser nativo da linguagem, é **muito** melhor do que a resposta abaixo, que é gambiarra pura (o fato de precisar checar duas vezes se tem um ponto no início com certeza é o "ponto alto"). Sei que o autor da pergunta é livre para aceitar a resposta, mas achei bom deixar o aviso aqui: já tem opção nativa na linguagem e eu só usaria uma função própria se fosse para fazer algo que a função nativa não oferece (o que claramente não é o caso aqui) :-)

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Adicione a função MakeDecimal em seu arquivo *script.js* e na função *igual()* em cada **case** você chama a função , assim:

```
resultado = MakeDecimal(Number(termo[0]) + Number(termo[2]));
```

//Funçao para transformar numero em decimal

```
function MakeDecimal(Number) {
  Number = Number + "" // Convert Number to string if not
  Number = Number.split('').reverse().join(''); //Reverse string
  var Result = "";
   for (i = 0; i <= Number.length; i += 3) {
     Result = Result + Number.substring(i, i + 3) + ".";
   }
     Result = Result.split('').reverse().join(''); //Reverse again
        if (!isFinite(Result.substring(0, 1))) Result = Result.substring(1, 
     Result.length); // Remove first dot, if have.
        if (!isFinite(Result.substring(0, 1))) Result = Result.substring(1, 
     Result.length); // Remove first dot, if have.
        return Result;
 }
```